# How do you convert an array of JavaScript objects to a single object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have this array:

```
var objectArray = [{url:"www.google.com", id: "google"}, 
{url:"www.apple.com", id: "apple"}, 
{url:"www.facebook.com", id: "facebook"}];
```

Is it possible to convert to a JavaScript object that is formed like this:

```
var newObject = {"google": "www.google.com", 
                 "apple": "www.apple.com",
                 "facebook": "www.facebook.com"};
```

Comment: The first 'array' looks like a json object.

Comment: @reporter What are you talking about? It looks an a JS array literal.

Comment: yes your right, I mixed the syntax a little bit with an array

Comment: @reporter JSON uses a subset of Javascript literal notation.

Comment: @Barmar as I have already wrote, I mixed up the syntax with the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can manually loop over the array and convert it.

```
var obj = {};
for (var i = 0; i < objectArray.length; i++) {
   obj[objectArray[i].id] = objectArray[i].url;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var m={};
objectArray.forEach(function (i){m[i.id]=i.url})
```